# Fuzzy logics, deduction theorem and strong conjunction

Tags: logic, fuzzy-logic

Hajek in *Metamathematics of Fuzzy Logic (1998)* states that for every extension of Basic logic a special version of the deduction theorem holds
$$A\vDash B\Leftrightarrow\exists n:\vDash\underbrace{A\&\ldots\&A}_{n\text{ times}}\rightarrow B\Leftrightarrow\exists n:\vDash\underbrace{A\rightarrow(\ldots\rightarrow(A}_{n\text{ times}}\rightarrow B)\ldots)$$

In general case (i.e. for any extension of Multiplicative Additive Intuitionistic Linear Logic without $\top$ and $\bot$ — MAILL$^-$), however (cf. *Proof Theory for Fuzzy Logics (2008)* by Metcalfe, Olivetti, and Gabbay), the following statement holds (using Hajek's notation)
$$A\vDash B\Leftrightarrow\exists n:\vDash\underbrace{(A\wedge e)\&\ldots\&(A\wedge e)}_{n\text{ times}}\rightarrow B$$

The question is as follows: does the clause $$A\vDash B\Leftrightarrow\exists n:\vDash\underbrace{A\rightarrow(\ldots\rightarrow(A}_{n\text{ times}}\rightarrow B)\ldots)$$ hold in all MAILL$^-$ extensions?

Comment: What is $e$? The usual Currying equivalence $(A \& B \to C) \leftrightarrow (A \to (B \to C))$ holds in these logics and if you iterate that you get the equivalence you are looking for apart from the unexplained $e$.

Comment: Thanks, Rob!

$e$ is a constant akin to $\top$ with the exception that it is not the case that $\forall A\vdash A\rightarrow e$.